# TypeScript and RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

TypeScript says:

> The property '`$1`' does not exist on value of type '`{ (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp; new(pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp; }`'

The type is explainable by looking at the definition from `lib.d.ts` that came with *TypeScript 0.8.2*:

```
interface RegExp {
    /** 
      * Executes a search on a string using a regular expression pattern, and returns an array containing the results of that search.
      * @param string The String object or string literal on which to perform the search.
      */
    exec(string: string): RegExpExecArray;
    /** 
      * Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether or not a pattern exists in a searched string.
      * @param string String on which to perform the search.
      */
    test(string: string): bool;
    /** Returns a copy of the text of the regular expression pattern. Read-only. The rgExp argument is a Regular expression object. It can be a variable name or a literal. */
    source: string;
    /** Returns a Boolean value indicating the state of the global flag (g) used with a regular expression. Default is false. Read-only. */
    global: bool;
    /** Returns a Boolean value indicating the state of the ignoreCase flag (i) used with a regular expression. Default is false. Read-only. */
    ignoreCase: bool;
    /** Returns a Boolean value indicating the state of the multiline flag (m) used with a regular expression. Default is false. Read-only. */
    multiline: bool;

    lastIndex: number;
}
declare var RegExp: {
    new (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp;
    (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp;
}
```

My question is how can I change/update this to allow me to reference `RegExp.$1`, `RegExp.$2`, etc.? Preferably something I can declare separately since I do not intend to directly edit `lib.d.ts` (which will most likely get replaced as it is updated)

I tried this to no avail:

```
declare var RegExp: {
    new (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp;
    (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp;
    $1: any;
    $2: any;
    $3: any;
    $4: any;
    $5: any;
    $6: any;
    $7: any;
    $8: any;
    $9: any;    
}
```

I guess they should be declared with type `string` actually. But in any case it doesn't remove the errors.

In addition to this I'm also curious about what this means exactly (why is it declared with and without a `new`?):

```
new (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp;
(pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `declare var` is close. Interfaces are open, so you can just write:

```
interface RegExp {
    $1: string;
    $2: string;
    // etc
}
```

Regarding the second one, it's because `new RegExp('[A-Z]')` and `RegExp('[A-Z]')` both work to create a RegExp (in type terms, it's both an invokable function and a constructor function).

Comment: It gives me "Duplicate identifier '$1'"

Comment: This is a bug in Visual Studio - you'll still be able to compile fine. This will get fixed in a future release; see http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/176

Comment: Doesn't address the original error though. Still says property `$1` etc do not exist

Comment: This works for me:
    interface RegExp {
        $1: string;
    }

    var x = /[A-Z]/;
    console.log(x.$1);

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't work for me. I'll make a file containing that and run `node tsc.js` over it when I get a chance (but it is 5pm now so that will have to wait)

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have tested this and it does not work. I keep getting `The property '$1' does not exist on value of type '{ (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp; new(pattern: string, flags?: string: RegExp; }'` I am going to have to refactor the existing code so it avoids using the `RegExp.$` properties

Comment: Actually, the code is a giant mess so I will simply use `var RegExp: any`

Comment: I see what you mean now (based on the CodePlex issue) - it wasn't clear to me that you were trying to declare this on the RegExp object itself rather than on the instance side (which makes sense now that I read the $n docs).

Comment: Is there no workaround? I can't get any work done now without refactoring this huge block of code.

Comment: You can always simply edit lib.d.ts and add those properties.

Comment: VS appears to put lib.d.ts on strict lockdown. I'm unable to edit the one referenced by the internal compiler. It appears as though I have to look through tsc.js itself and manually compile (with node) which is hardly a productive workflow...

Comment: Maybe I can specify the `nolib` option so I can use my own copy of lib.d.ts? How do I do that in VS?

Comment: You'll need to edit this in two places:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.d.ts`
and
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\lib.d.ts`
using your editor of choice running with administrator privileges.

Trying to work around this any other way isn't likely to be a productive path.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I can't believe there isn't a config field to specify options to send to tsc.