# can I use an interface for a property list?

Tags: interface, typescript

I have an interface def
In order to use in many places, i understand I have to split it into its own file (at least with ES5 output). So:

//ICommand.ts>

```
interface RegExp {
    $1: string;
    $2: string;
    $3: string;
    // etc
}

interface IBotCommand {
    regex: RegExp
    // fixme - clearer def
    // cmd: ():Output
    cmd: any
}

export = IBotCommand;
```

//BotCommand.ts >

```
import ICommand = require("./ICommand");
class BotCommand {
    commandList: ICommand
```

But this gives `Error: cannot find name ICommand`
Is this possible? What is the best syntax?

Answer (score 0):

it seems this maybe down to my environment not recompiling these scripts.

also the RegExp definition is taken from here:
[TypeScript and RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650014/typescript-and-regexp) 
and may not be fully functional

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the interface like this:

```
export = IBotCommand;
// but you are importing it with:
import ICommand = require('./ICommand');
```

With you export being the way it is, change your import to be:

```
import { IBotCommand } from './ICommand';
```

If you'd like to import it like this:

```
import ICommand from './ICommand';
```

then you will want to export it like this:

```
export default IBotCommand;
```

If you don't use `default` then you must use the object notation to reference your imports.

There is a caveat to the object notation, in that you could also do this:

```
import * as cmds from './ICommand';
// and use it like this:
class SomeClass implements cmds.IBotCommand {}
```

Comment: is this ES6 syntax? i'm targeting ES5 at the moment. which one is more reliable?

Comment: This is utilizing the es6 module syntax, but the TypeScript compiler can be configured to output ES5 code